# Как классифицировать вопрос без ответа

Tags: обсуждение, качество-вопроса

Есть такой вопрос: [Как устранить конфликт скриптов jQuery](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/309649/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-jquery). Судя по комментарию автора вопроса, на него были или комментарии или даже ответы. Впрос вроде бы был решен, но ответа нет, как в итоге был решен - непонятно, что ответить - непонятно и закрывать его или нет - тоже непонятно.

Закрыть его как "не вопроизводимый" не очень корректно, поскольку проблема воспроизводится, просто приведенный код делает не совсем то, чего ожидал автор.
С другой стороны от этого вопроса, по моему мнению, не будет пользы для других посетителей, поскольку довольно специфичная проблема.

Что делать с вопросами, имеющими похожие проблемы?

**Добавлено** Кстати вопрос привели в порядок, может я зря свой задавал :\

Comment: Собственно, это и есть ответ. Такой вопрос нужно по возможности привести в порядок. Например перенести ответ из комментария в ответ, вручную. Подробнее: [Конвертирование и редактирование комментариев?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/23), [Вопрос с ответом в комментариях: копировать решение в свой ответ или звать модератора для преобразования коммента в в ответ?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1411)

Comment: @NickVolynkin На самом деле сейчас просто этот вопрос попался и мне показалось что я уже видел несколько вопросов от которых, прямо скажем, толку мало (вопросы в стиле "вот я написал и не работает" и ниже комментарий "все я разобрался, всем спасибо") и ответов нету, но подходящей причины, чтобы закрыть тоже не вижу.

Comment: если разобрался, но ответа нет — то «невозможно воспроизвести». Кто ж знает, как он там разобрался. Или когда ответ «я ребутнул комп и оно заработало» — то же самое.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, или когда давний вопрос про (уже) неактуальную версию чего-нибудь.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да, если только эта версия не популярна в каком-нибудь legacy-коде.